# Worklight & Bluemix Push gives double notifications

Tags: android, cordova, push, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I followed the great tutorial of extending an android application with Push cloud service, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-android-push-app/index.html

I am developing an app with Worklight, my main activity is extending CordovaActivity and implements WLInitWebFrameworkListener.
 My problem is, that my application gives me 2 notifications in the notification bar. One with the default icon of a star (since I have not added a notification icon), and the another notification with the push.png that worklight already put in my drawables for me.

Have anyone used the Push service in a workligth app? How do I make sure I only get one notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndroidManifest.xml may have push notification entries for Worklight and Android both. Remove the entries for Worklight and then try . You should see only one push notification.

Answer (score 2):

This was answered from someone on the Bluemix team here:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/19343/double-push-notifications/?community=bluemix

Malin, would you please mark this as answered here as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked the Worklight Getting Started Module about Push Notification?
If not, you can take a look on it here (Under the "Notifications" topic):
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_notif

But understand that Worklight push notification goes through a Worklight Server (your own) and is not related to the Bluemix (cloud) push notification mechanism described in the article that you mentioned. Basically those are two different ways to achieve the same goal of push notifications.